# PHPExcel output error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have the following code which I run on localhost and works perfectly:

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($excel);    
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$excel_file.'"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The same code uploaded on another host returns a 404 "File Not Found" error.

Any ideea why?

Comment: 404 not found likely means that the page isn't at the URL where you expect it to be, but it's nothing to do with PHPExcel

Comment: The page is exactly at the URL where I expect it to be.

Comment: Note that you're sending the wrong headers for the filetype: The Excel2007 Writer is used to create an OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) file, which has a mime type of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`; a mime type of `application/vnd.ms-excel` identifies a BIFF format (xls) file, created by the Excel5 Writer

Comment: Check your webserver logs, but a 404 return status means `page not found`

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in your .htaccess files that might be rewriting the request?

Comment: I have no rewrite rules. I also tried with xlsx and that mime type, but still the same error. Its not actually a 404, it says: "File not found. Firefox can't find the file at [...]. Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors. Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted."

Comment: Can/have you set

 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

at the start of the script? Just to make sure it's not something completely different like a routing to an non existing error page as some extensions are missing (just guessing).

Comment: Guess no 2: does your server have the zip extension enabled? From my experience not all (shared) hosters have it. Ok, the error message does not make much sense with this reason, but who knows how the server is configured and/or what framework you are using.

Comment: Have you checked the webserver logs yet? This is generally an error thrown by a webserver when it can't find the file the serve: if it can find your php script, then you won't get a 404 error unless the php script itself explicitly sends a 404 status

Comment: Yes, my server has the zip extension enabled. Also, I checked the logs and no error has been logged.

Comment: @PSyche does it work if you save the content to a file instead of sending it to the browser?

Comment: So if the webserver log doesn't report a 404, what status does it say the response was to the request?

Comment: jamie0726, yes, it works. Mark Baker seems to be a 500.

Comment: @Psyche you might find this posting useful: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/250120

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue. It was working in local but not on live server.
Just confirm below installation on live server and it will work.

- PHP extension php_zip enabled
- PHP extension php_xml enabled
- PHP extension php_gd2 enabled

Answer (score 0):

Today I combacted against this problem.

I saw that Firefox told me "File not found", but HTTP code in the header was a 500 (server error).

I had a mistake writing a formula; once I corrected the formula the error is disappeared.

I've error reporting at paranoid level, display errors active, and I watched at apache error*.log files, but I've received no comunications from the library/ PHP / Apache about the error.

I foudn the error just commenting out one group row at time in the code until I catched the error.

I've no explanation why this error throws non logs.

Comment: It could be that whatever is throwing the error is suppressed with `@`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php